# Как записывать и считывать файлы на Google drive

Tags: java, android

В приложении настроил google drive, авторизация проходит, но мне нужно теперь копировать в Google drive файлы и считывать оттуда эти файлы если отсутствует локальная версия, в примерах и документации не нашел примеров как это можно сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У GoogleDrive есть хороший API для этого дела, описание [записи](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file) и [чтения](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files) файлов тут

Comment: именно по этой документации я не смог разобраться как все это дело делать,  нашел как создавать DriveFile DriveFile file = Drive.DriveApi.getFile(mGoogleApiClient, driveid, где мне брать этот driveid,

Comment: Насколько я помню там есть небольшая сложность - документ, который хочешь скачать из приложения, должен был ранее этим приложением же и быть загружен, и каждому файлу будет автоматически присвоен свой DriveID. Далее при загрузке файла из переменной класса *MetadataBufferResult*  получаем DriveID - `mdbr.getMetadataBuffer().get(i).getDriveId()`

Comment: предпологается что я буду закачивать файл и этот файл можно будет копировать в каталог приложения  с другого устройства с этим же логином и приложением, сейчас предпологается так, я создаю файл в google drive и его не изменяю если приложение будет переустановлено я скачаю эти файлы заново.

Comment: Да, в принципе это возможно, но все таки интеграция GoogleDrive довольно сильная морока. Не пробовал  просто размещать файлы на каком нибудь бесплатном хостинге? Организация запросов к хостингу  в приложении будет попроще

Comment: да, возможно пользователей будет много, и нужно хранить картинки пользователей, а это лучше хранить в их собственном облаке, трудно внедрить но придется с ним разбираться